# Cannot set contentSize of an UIScrollView created via loadView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I need to set the `contentSize` of an `UIScrollView` outside of the `loadView` function.

However when trying to do so, I have the error `'UIView' does not have a member named 'contentSize'`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var bigRect = view.bounds
        bigRect.size.width *= CGFloat(someInt)

        view.contentSize = bigRect // 'UIView' does not have a member named 'contentSize'
    }

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    }

}
```

Thanks !

**Notes:**

- in the console, `view` is indeed an instance of `UIScrollView` but sending it `contentSize` gives me the same error.
- replacing `view` by `self.view` doesn't solve the issue ; there is no local variable interfering here.

Comment: is 'view' defined in code or in IB? Maybe its defined as a UIView...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view` is an `UIViewController` attribute of type `UIView`. So you should configure the scroll view within a local variable first and then set it to the view variable :

```
override func loadView() {
    var scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    scrollView.contentSize = <Whatever>
    view = scrollView
}
```

If you plan to change the scroll view later you should consider either:

- Add a new attribute to your class (good practice)
- Or cast anytime the `view` attribute `as UIScrollView` (pretty bad practice)

E.g:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var scrollView:UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var bigRect = view.bounds
        bigRect.size.width *= CGFloat(someInt)

        scrollView.contentSize = bigRect.size
    }

    override func loadView() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        view = scrollView
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Why is casting `view` as `UIScrollView` considered a bad practice?

Comment: @delba I think he means that casting every time you use the view variable is bad practice as it is repeated code - you could just do it once and store it in a variable so not to repeat yourself, therefore making it better practice. If you only every use the variable once, then I don't think it matters which way you decide to do it.

Comment: `UITableViewController` also declares a `tableView` attribute (which is the view casted as an `UITableView`) so I now think that this solution offers a good "symmetry"

Comment: Yes, the main reason is that you need the `view` attribute to use it as the view of the screen (read `UIViewController`). The `scrollView` attribute will be related directly to the scrolling view. Even if both are the same instance in this case, there are 2 semantically different things. You could (for instance) want to add another `UIView` as `view` over the `scrollView` to add other elements on the page. And you want to be able to do it quite easily. As writing a new attribute won't take you more than a few seconds. It worths it.

Comment: And there are other reasons like code readability or safety (even more on Swift where all is strong typed, but this is just my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming it to scrollView instead of view as view is already a variable attached to all UIViewControllers so it might be getting confused. Unless of course you are trying to say that you replaced the view with a scrollView in the storyboard. In this case, you need to cast the view as a scrollView as shown below:

```
(view as UIScrollView).contentSize
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because technicaly it's the fastest way to answer the question.