# Swift reference to property and pass it around

Tags: swift

How can I assign a reference to property to a variable and pass it around. Something similar to function where we can do something like this:

```
class Foo {

    func executeTask() {
        print("executeTask called")
    }

    var name: String = "name1"
}

// get reference to the executeTask method
let x = Foo.executeTask

// later we can call the executeTask method but using the x variable
x(Foo())()
```

But how can we do same thing for properties. I was expecting that:

```
// get reference to the executeTask method
let y = Foo.name

// later we can call name property but using the y variable
y(Foo())()
```

but this gives the error: `instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'Foo'`

Edit:
Guys, the question is definitely not about accessing a property of an instance variable to get its current value. It would be a trivial question to ask.
Look again to the `executeTask` example. The `executeTask` was defined as `func executeTask()` So x in the example is a reference to function. I want a very similar thing to get reference to property where I can call later to get the value of the property and please don't tell me to use a Container class.

Edit 2:
Explained with a better example.

Comment: Foo.executeTask exist before initialization. all instances of the class 'sharing' the same function. but the property doesn't exist before initialization. functions are like 'static' properties. if you define you property as static, it will be accessible too ... what you are trying to do, is impossible (by my best knowledge )

Comment: ... think about the protocol. the function in the protocol is declared, but not defined. should it be 'accessible'? function in class is defined, has a type, has a value. that is, why it is accessible. the property in class must be declared, but not defined  before init.

Comment: What about computed properties? They are like functions. I want reference to the implementation.

Comment: unfortunately, if not defined as static, there are not accessible. the logic is the same. if the value is instance dependent, you are not able to know the value before initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KeyPath might not be exactly what you requested, but might be close enough:

```
let y = \Foo.name
let z = Foo()
z[keyPath: y]
```

For more information, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/

Answer (score 5):

A function can be used as a closure, a property can't.
A solution is to add a custom function to access the property, there is no direct way.

```
class Foo {

  var name: String = "name1"

  func getName() -> String {
    return name
  }
}

let y = Foo.getName
y( Foo() )()
```

Comment: That's definitely not what I mean. I want to get the reference to the property similar to the reference to the function. So that I can call the property later.

Comment: Getting the value of a property is exactly the same as calling a function. In both cases the caller must be an instance of the type, not the type itself.

Comment: You still don't understand me. I don't want to get the value or call the function now. I just want to get reference to the implementation where I can call it later. The function can be assigned to closures, I want a similar thing.

Comment: Then please update your question to show an example what you mean

Comment: I updated the question with the better illustration. Let me know if it is still confusing. Thanks very much for helping me out.

Comment: That's a workaround I already know. I want to see if you know a way to directly have a reference to property implementation.

Comment: There is no direct way

Comment: You are sure of that. If yes, please remove the first part of your answer and just leave the edit and add that no direct way and I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to change the property later, you should add a new `attribute` to your class, for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var scrollView:UIScrollView!

...
}
```

Then you can access and change it like so:

```
scrollView.contentSize = bigRect.size
```

For more informations, please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25816878/1938719).

Comment: That's definitely not what I mean. I want to get the reference to the property similar to the reference to the function. So that I can call the property later.
I was refering to uiscrollview.contentsize as an example. In general I want to get the property of AnyClassType.propertyName similar to when you can call AnyClassType.methodName.

Comment: I don't know why you downvote my answer if the problem was you not explaining your problem. Clearly, more people understood it just as I did.

Comment: Sorry about that. If you edited your answer I can remove the downvote.